# Entity Framework 6 - Passing Table Valued Parameter to Table Valued Function, returning IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework-6, user-defined-functions, table-valued-parameters

I want to call a Table Valued Function from entity framework, and have it return an IQueryable.  The code I have is:

```
// Defines table-valued function, which must return IQueryable<T>.
[Function(FunctionType.TableValuedFunction, nameof(ufnGetContactInformation), Schema = dbo)]
public IQueryable<ContactInformation> ufnGetContactInformation(
    [Parameter(DbType = "int", Name = "PersonID")]int? personId)
{
    ObjectParameter personIdParameter = personId.HasValue
        ? new ObjectParameter("PersonID", personId)
        : new ObjectParameter("PersonID", typeof(int));

    return this.ObjectContext().CreateQuery<ContactInformation>(
        $"[{nameof(this.ufnGetContactInformation)}](@{nameof(personId)})", personIdParameter);
}
```

However, I also want to be able to pass into the TVF a Table Valued Parameter (so I can pass a list of Id's into the TVF).  I've found code that can do this using a DataTable which references the user-defined type I have in the db, eg:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id");
dt.Rows.Add(1);
dt.Rows.Add(2);
dt.Rows.Add(3);

var idList = new SqlParameter("idList", SqlDbType.Structured);
warnings.Value = dt;
warnings.TypeName = "dbo.udt_idList";

entities.ExecuteStoredProcedure("usp_TableValuedFunc", idList);
```

The problem is, the second code uses SQLParameter, and the first code uses ObjectParameter.  It appears that ObjectParameter won't allow for user-defined-types to be supplied, and any code EF uses that accepts SQLParameter won't allow me to return an IQueryable from a TVF.  Any ideas, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing right now

Comment: @ganjeii fyi I never managed to solve this, I ended up using dynamic SQL for the query instead so I could build it exactly as I needed to, and just inject the list of params directly into the query

Comment: I was actually able to solve this by passing a list of values in a comma delimited string. Then split them inside the TVF and returned them as a table

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `idList.Value = dt;` & `idList.TypeName = "dbo.udt_idList";` instead of `warnings`?